# PHP-MySQLi connection randomly fails with "Cannot assign requested address"

Tags: php, mysql, debian

Since about 2 weeks I'm dealing with one of the weirdest problems in LAMP stack.
Long story short randomly connection to MySQL server is failing with error message:

```
Warning:  mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Cannot assign requested address in ..
```

The MySQL  is on different "box", hosted at Rackspace Cloud
Today we downgraded it's version to

```
Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.42, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64).
```

The DB server is pretty busy dealing with  Queries per second avg: 5327.957 according to it's status variable.

MySQL is in  log-warnings=9 but no warring for connection refused are logged.
Both site and gearman workers scripts fail with that error at let's say 1% probability.
No server load DO NOT seems to be a factor as we monitor. (CPU load, IO load or MySQL load)
The maximum DB connections (max_connections) are setted to 200 but we have never dealed with more than 100 simultaneous connections to the database

It happens with and without the firewall software.

I suspect TCP Networking problem rather than PHP/MySQL configurationn problem.

Can anyone give me clue how to find it?

UPDATE:

The connection code is:

```
$this->_mysqli = mysqli_init(); 
$this->_mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 120); 
$this->_mysqli->real_connect($dbHost,$dbUserName, $dbPassword, $dbName); 

if (!is_null($this->_mysqli->connect_error)) {
    $ping = $this->_mysqli->ping(); 

    if(!$ping){
        $error = 'HOST: {'.$dbHost.'};MESSAGE: '. $this->_mysqli->connect_error ."\n"; 
        DataStoreException::raiseHostUnreachable($error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your connection code? Failing that, try connecting to 127.0.0.1 to eliminate any DHCP interference.

Comment: We connect to internal network IP address

Comment: My suggestion for troubleshooting is to try and replicate it while monitoring outbound connections on that box. Use wireshark or whatever you need. When it fails, be sure it actually had an outbound connection. Trace through the network from there. I did some googling, and all the results suggested a network issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[MySQL: Using giant number of connections](http://peter-zaitsev.livejournal.com/14954.html)

What are dangers of frequent connects ?
It works well, with exception of some extreme cases. If you get hundreds of connects per second from the same box you may get into running out of local port numbers. The way to fix it could be - decrease "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout" on linux (this breaks TCP/IP standard but you might not care in your local network), increase "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range" on the *client*. Other OS have similar settings. You also may use more web boxes or multiple IP for your same database host to work around this problem. I've realy seen this in production.

Some background about this problem:
TCP/IP connection is identified by localip:localport remoteip:remote port. We have MySQL IP and Port as well as client IP fixed in this case so we can only vary local port which has finite range. Note **even after you close connection TCP/IP stack has to keep the port reserved for some time**, this is where tcp_fin_timeout comes from.

Answer (score 22):

I had this problem and solved it using persistent connection mode, which can be activated in mysqli by pre-fixing the database hostname with a 'p:'

```
$link = mysqli_connect('p:localhost', 'fake_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

From: 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php :

> The idea behind persistent connections is that a connection between a
>   client process and a database can be reused by a client process,
>   rather than being created and destroyed multiple times. This reduces
>   the overhead of creating fresh connections every time one is required,
>   as unused connections are cached and ready to be reused.
>   ...
>
> To open a persistent
>   connection you must prepend p: to the hostname when connecting.

Comment: I am not sure about other answers but this is the only solution worked for me.

Comment: This is a great solution where it will work! Our experience was, that not all code works equally well with persistent connections. If your code works well with persistent connections this will VERY substantially reduce the number of new connections made.

Comment: I am already having persistent connections but this problem still persists. Same error but we are also crossing max connection limits. I am not sure whether the fix suggested by @fgwaller would help.

Answer (score 16):

With Vicidial I have run into the same problem frequently, due to the kind of programming used, new MYSQL connections have to be established (very) frequently from a number of vicidial components, we have systems hammering the db server with over 10000 connections per second, most of which are serviced within a few ms and which are closed within a second or less. From experience I can tell you that in a local network, with close to no lost packages, tcp_fin_timeout can be reduced all the way down to 3 with no problems showing up.

Typical linux commands to diagnose if connections waiting to be closed is your problem are:

```
netstat -anlp | grep :3306 | grep TIME_WAIT -wc
```

which will show you the number of connections that are waiting to be closed completely.

```
netstat -nat | awk {'print $5'} | cut -d ":" -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

which will show the connections per connected host, allowing you to identify which other host is folding your system if there are multiple candidates.

To test the fix you can just

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
echo "3" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
```

which will temporarily set the tcp_fin_timeout to 3 sec and tell you how many seconds it was before, so you can revert to the old value for testing.

As a permanent fix I would suggest you add the following line to /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=3
```

Within a good local network with should not cause any trouble, if you do run into problems e.g. because of packet loss, you can try

```
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=0
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=10
```

Wiche allows more time for the connection to close and tries to reuse same ip:port combinations for new connections to the same host:service combination.

OR

```
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=10
```

Which will even more aggressively try to reuse connections, what can however create new problems with other applications for example with your webserver. So you should try the simple solution first, in most cases it will already fix your problem without any bad side effects!

Good Luck!

Comment: Lifesaver! - this worked wonders in an Ubuntu 20.04 EC2 and Aurora MySQL. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem. Although "tcp_fin_timeout" and "ip_local_port_range" solutions worked, the real problem was poorly writen PHP script, which just created new connection almost every second query it made to database. Rewriting script to connect just once solved all trouble. 
Please be aware that lowering "tcp_fin_timeout" value may be dangerous, as some code may depend on DB connection being still there after some time after connection. It's rather a dirty duct tape and bubble gum path than real solution.

Comment: I fully agree with the first part, the proper solution is to use persistent connections. If this is not possible tcp_fin_timeout can be lowered with no risk, the long timeout is not warranted when slow connections usually have multiple kbit. tcp_fin_timeout only affects already closed connections, so nothing should expect them to be around any longer. The timeout originally solved problems of late (60 seconds later!) arriving packages, in today's age I have not seen any that late. Reducing the time before the socket can be used again to 3 seconds (in a LAN) will not cause any harm.

Answer (score 1):

Vicidial servers regularly require increasing the connection limit in MySQL. Many installations (and we've seen and worked on a lot of them) have had to do this by modifying the limit

Additionally there have been reports of conntract_Max requiring increase in

```
/sbin/sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=196608
```

when the problem turns out to be networking related.

Also note that Vicidial has some specific suggested settings and even some enterprise settings for mysql configuration. Have a look in my-bigvici.cnf in /usr/src/astguiclient/conf for some configuration ideas that may open your mysql server up a bit.

So far, no problems have resulted from increasing connection limits, just additional resources used. Since the purpose of the server is to make this application work, dedicating resources to this application does not seem like a problem. LOL