# Mysql PHP dropping connection during long script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having a problem that I can't seem to figure out involving a long php script that does not complete due to a Database connection failure.

I am using PHP 5.5.25 and MySQL 5.6.23, with the mysqli interface.

The script uses the TCPDF library to create a PDF of a financial report.  Overall it runs fine. However, when the data set gets large (the report can iterate over numerous accounts to create a multiple page report with all the accounts that match criteria) it will fail after about 30 seconds (not exactly 30, sometimes a couple of seconds more by time stamps).  It seems to run fine for about 25-35 loops, but more than that causes the problem.

I don't think its an issue of timing out (although it certainly could be). I have PHP set to fairly generous amounts of resources to process this.

```
max_execution_time = 600 
memory_limit = 2048M
```

The script does hit the DB pretty hard with hundreds of queries per second. As best as I can tell from some stats from the DB, there are only a couple of active connections at a time so it does not appear that the I am anywhere close to the default setting of 150 max connections.

This is the error I get when it eventually fails with a large data set.

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Can't assign requested address in...
>
> Fatal error: Database connection failed: Can't assign requested address in...

Does anyone have any suggestions on what may be causing the script to eventually not be able to connect to the DB and fail to complete?  I've tried searching for some answers but pretty much everything I have found so far about Database Connection failures are not being able to connect at all, rather than not being able to connect midway through a large script.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Duplicate of [PHP-MySQLi connection randomly fails with “Cannot assign requested address”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210270/php-mysqli-connection-randomly-fails-with-cannot-assign-requested-address) ??

Comment: "The script does hit the DB pretty hard with hundreds of queries per second." Are you opening a different connection for each one? Because its probably the number of connections. Just open one per PHP page at most.

Comment: I think that this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210270/php-mysqli-connection-randomly-fails-with-cannot-assign-requested-address

Comment: isn't it this `show variables where variable_name in ('interactive_timeout','wait_timeout');`  The fact that it is 30 sec or 60 sec sounds suspicious as such, in shared hosting environments at least

Comment: I know there might be no link with your problem but mysqli is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) for your PHP version.

Comment: I did see that other question that looked similar.  I am not sure if this is the same issue as it appears in that other case, the MySQL server was on a different box than the PHP server if I understood.  Also, I am running on OS X 10.10, not linux, so the exact solution may not be the same.

Comment: Hi Drew,  I check those variables as you suggested and they are set at 28800, which I believe is seconds, so I'm not sure if that is the issue.   Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: The suggestion to verify that the connection was only being called once per page was spot on.  The script was calling some functions which connected to the database.  I moved the connection code out of the function and called it as a global and that solved the problem.  Something I never noticed before on the old hardware since it ran much slower and did not create too many new connections each second.

Comment: @Aurelien: mysqli is NOT deprecated. That's the mysql (no i) extension.

Comment: @symcbean: you are right, I apologize, I made a mistake mysqli is absolutely not deprecated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP-MySQLi connection randomly fails with "Cannot assign requested address"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210270/php-mysqli-connection-randomly-fails-with-cannot-assign-requested-address)

Answer (score -2):

> I don't think it's an issue of timing out

You should *know*.

It seems strange that the issue is arising so long after the start of execution. Would it have been so hard to check what the timeout is? To try changing it? To add some logging to your code?

The other thing you should be checking is whether the script is opening a single connection and reusing it or constantly opening new connections.

Without seeing the code, its hard to say for sure, but a single script executing hundreds of queries per second for tens of seconds sounds like the split between SQL and PHP logic has been very poorly thought out.

Comment: It was multiple connections constantly being opened, rather than using a single connection.   I'm sure the logic could be better written, but this script does produce a 100+ page pdf report that has a graph on each page, slicing and dicing financial data to make it understandable for those who are not accountants. I run it once a month, so for the 100 seconds it takes, I'm not too worried about hammering the server that hard.